# Can the minimum of two consecutive prime gaps become arbitary large?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

Here :

https://oeis.org/A023186

the so-called "Lonely primes" are shown.

Let $$[a,b,c]$$ be a triple of consecutive primes and define $$d:=\min(c-b,b-a)$$

My question :

> Can we prove that $d$ can become arbitary large ? In other words, can we prove that the minimum of two consecutive prime gaps can become arbitary large ?

With the chinese remainder theorem we can construct a positive integer $N$, such that the each number in the range $$[N-d,N+d]$$ except $N$ (d is some positive integer ) must have a prime factor not exceeding $p_{2d}$ But can we show that $N$ can be prime (perhaps by using the Dirichlet theorem) and that also $N-d>p_{2d}$ can be satisfied ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you read that OEIS page you linked to, it says

> Erdős and Suranyi call these reclusive primes and **prove that there are an infinite number of them**.

(Emphasis mine.) Each lonely prime is the $b$ of a consecutive prime triple $[a, b, c]$ for which $d = \min(b-a, c-b)$ is larger than for any previous prime triple. Since this sequence of lonely primes continues infinitely, there must be arbitrarily large $d$.

In particular, two consecutive gaps of size at least $2k$ must occur at the latest on either side of lonely prime number $k$ (counting $2$ as the $0$th lonely prime). If you instead take sequence number [120937](https://oeis.org/A120937), then it duplicates the lonely primes such that it happens for the first time *exactly* at term number $k$.

Comment: How difficult is the Erdos-Suranyi result?